# Developing 2D Games on Android

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

Are there any useful libraries that can be used to make 2d games?  I am familiar with android development, but never made any games.

I guess its more of a general questions for helping me to get started.

Thank you.

Comment: "Were there any specific libraries that flappy birds used? ", as the developer of that game, I can say...wait, that's not me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As per the guidelines you agreed to prior to posting this, this isn't a valid question here.

Comment: ::sigh:: and someone needs their upvote priveledges revoked.

Comment: Whats wrong with my question? Its my first time asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Neglecting what @BrianRoach is saying, check out my answer. I've used AndEngine before and it works really well to make 2D games such as Flappy Bird, Angry Birds, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately these questions attract low rep users doing the wrong thing. As per the guidelines,Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @BrianRoach I'm in the business of helping people who take the initiate to seek help. Who is anyone to take that right away from someone? Sure, my answer may be opinionated as it refers to a library I've used and enjoyed before, but I'm helping a person who wants to further develop their coding and computer science abilities. Nobody should limit the right to learn. Not I. Not you. Not anybody. Therefore, I will gladly share mine in the hopes that one day, this guy is in my position to help the next guy. Inspiration to learn shouldn't be restricted, guidelines or not.

Comment: I guess I was wrong in specifying a game that already existed. Instead  , I should have generalized it more, but again I guess having generalized questions is wrong as well?

Comment: @Adam I'm really not interested in your rationalizations for violating this site's rules and guidelines.

Comment: @BrianRoach You think you're the elite of a website that's free to use for anybody who wishes to use it, with your reputation in the thousands. Let the guy learn; there's no point in closing the question. You were in his position once also, albeit long enough ago you forgot.

Comment: @Adam I'm contributing to a website that has rules and guidelines. I happen to agree with those rules. You're choosing to violate those rules, which reduces the value of said site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try out [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)? It's a free 2D OpenGL Android Library that you can use to create 2D games on the Android system with OpenGL.